# How to group Rows based on cell values - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of items organized in :

(Column "A")

- project
- activities
- sub-activities

They have a specific index (In Column "B")

- Project Index = 0
- Activity Index= 1
- Sub-activity Index = 2

An example data looks like this :

Column "A"

- ProjectName
- Activity 1
- Sub-activity 1
- Sub-activity 2
- Activity 2
- Activity 3
- Sub-activity 1

Column "B"

- 0
- 1
- 2
- 2
- 1
- 1
- 2

I tried with this :

```
Public Sub RaggruppaProgetto()

  Dim lvlData, rCel As Range

  Set lvlData = Range("B" & TrovaInizioProgetti(activeCell), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

  With lvlData
    On Error Resume Next
    .Rows.Ungroup
    .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With

  For Each rCel In lvlData

    If rCel = "2" Then
      Rows(rCel.Row).Group
      rCel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

  Next

End Sub
```

What I expect is, when the macro runs, all the level 2 should group under the level 1 and all the level 1 (with the level 2 grouped) should group under level 0.

Comment: Please note that `Dim lvlData, rCel As Range` initializes lvlData as `Variant`, not as a `Range`. Instead use `Dim lvlData As Range, rCel As Range`. Also use `rCel.Value2 = "2"` instead of `rCel = "2"`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try.